# How to approve google Ad-Sense application

Tags: adsense

Filed to approve ad-sense on our websites [wikifeed.in](https://www.wikifeed.in)

Google replied:

1. It’s important for sites displaying Google ads to offer significant value to the user. As a publisher, you must provide unique and relevant content that gives users a reason to visit your site first.

   2. Don’t place ads on auto-generated pages or pages with little to no original content.
   3. Your site should also provide a good user experience through clear navigation and organization. Users should be able to easily click through your pages and find the information they’re seeking.

Kindly help to approve.

Comment: And what is your problem? Can't you just do what google says you should improve?

Comment: Tried more then 3 times to approve ad-sense but every time its rejected

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because question is not about programming. It's about google's rules for adsense